# how to set final size when sending a reset frame in http3

Tags: nginx, quic, http3

The following scenario：

1. Sender have sent continuous 10000 bytes
2. Receiver ACK 0 - 8000(sender have recived those acks)
3. Now, Sender will send a reset frame, the question is how to set the " final size"

> a. final size is 10000
> b. final size is 8000

Looking at RFC 9000(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9000#section-4.5) witch
describing:

> 4.5.  Stream Final Size
>
> The final size is the amount of flow control credit that is
> consumed    by a stream.  Assuming that every contiguous byte on the
> stream was    sent once, the final size is the number of bytes sent.
> More    generally, this is one higher than the offset of the byte with
> the    largest offset sent on the stream, or zero if no bytes were
> sent.

I think the final size should be 10000, and sender must not send any more(transmission and
retransmission) on the identified stream, am I right?
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9000#section-19.4

> After sending a RESET_STREAM, an endpoint ceases transmission and
> retransmission of STREAM frames on the identified stream.  A receiver
> of RESET_STREAM can discard any data that it already received on that
> stream.

And nginx'iquic may have some problems, nginx will retranmit frames when nginx have sent a reset frame(for example: nginx http3 have sent all data to ctx->frames, then qs will be deleted)

```
   void
    ngx_quic_resend_frames(ngx_connection_t *c, ngx_quic_send_ctx_t *ctx)
    {
    case NGX_QUIC_FT_STREAM:
        qs = ngx_quic_find_stream(&qc->streams.tree, f->u.stream.stream_id);

        if (qs) {
            if (qs->send_state == NGX_QUIC_STREAM_SEND_RESET_SENT
                || qs->send_state == NGX_QUIC_STREAM_SEND_RESET_RECVD)
            {
                ngx_quic_free_frame(c, f);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final size is definitely 10000, as flow control credit is consumed by sending data on a stream; whether it is acknowlegded or not does not matter.

Indeed, after sending the reset-stream frame:

- no new data should be send (this would be a violation of the final size leading to a fatal error as described in section 4.5
- no retransmissions should be performed

The 3rd question is unclear to me. I'm not a ngx-quic expert, but from the code it posted i would guess it does not retransmit, as the frame is freed ;-)